# Dynamical Systems: Disease model, what happens to variable $m$?

Tags: dynamical-systems

In the diagram it shows that people can die from other causes at a rate $m$, however in the equations the $m$ and the variable $M_a$ disappear. Is there a mathematical reason for this to happen?

[image]

Comment: Equations (1)-(2)-(3) describe a restricted version of the model, when $m=0$. This might be explained on the previous page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that